# Why targetNamespaces?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

First of all , I know there's a similar thread that tries to answer the same question.But Unfortunately for me , that does not clear the confusion.

So here's the question again :

Why do we need to specify targetNamespace in xml schema documents?
We could define multiple namespaces in an instanceDocument & associate these namespaces to corresponding schema documents.Where does the need of targetNamespace come up?

Comment: If you know of a similar thread, why not link to it rather than make us search for it before knowing whether to post an answer that you might just dismiss?

Comment: My Bad. Here's the similar thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853484/why-do-we-need-targetnamespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

targetNamespace is the namespace that is going to be assigned to the schema you are creating. It is the namespace an instance is going to use to access the types it declares. In the following code, the schema will be assigned to the namespace `http://www.somewebsite.com/Something`

```
 <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
targetNamespace="http://www.somewebsite.com/Something/Foo">  
...  
</schema>
```

In an XML document instance, you declare the namespaces you are going to be using by means of the xmlns attribute. For example:

```
<purchaseOrder xmlns="http://www.somewebsite.com/Something/Foo"  
xmlns:addr="http://www.somewebsite.com/Something/Foo/addr">  
  <accountName>Shanita</accountName>  
  <accountNumber>123456</accountNumber>  
  <addr:street>20 King St</addr:street>  
</purchaseOrder>
```

The default namespace here is `http://www.somewebsite.com/Something/Foo`, which makes reference to the schema previously created. This namespace applies to the element that declares it, and its child elements, unles they are prefixed. In the example, all the elements belong to the default namespace, except `addr:street`. Since it is prefixed, it belongs to the addr namespace (`xmlns:addr="http://www.somewebsite.com/Something/Foo/addr`")