# Difference between Default Namespace and targetnamespace? null namespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I've read through several posts found over google and the wiki article about namespace and xml scheme, and i dont know.. i just cant quite understand the difference between the default namespace and the targetnamespace..

So the default namespace is the namespace used by default (if no other namespace are defined for certain elements)
while the targetnamespace seems to be of the same use?

Also as I've read, attributes are by default signed to the null namespace?
what is the nullnamespace?

In my example:

```
<test xmlns="www.example.org" attribute1="1" attribute2="tbla" attribute3="helloworld">
  <child1></child1>
</test>
```

so child1 is in the www.example.org namespace while attribute1 /attribute2 and attribute 3 are in the null namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from this question: [Why do we need targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853484/why-do-we-need-targetnamespace)

My understanding is that the targetNamespace was developed to match the XML schema (.xsd) to the XML document using the schema. But the above question and discussion answers it in more depth.